# Transparent medium permeability approximation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

> An electromagnetic wave with an intensity of 50 W/m^2 enters a medium that has a refractive index of $n$ without any loss. The ratio of magnitudes of the electric field as well as the ratio of the magnitudes of the magnetic fields of the wave before and after entering the medium are respectively given by: -JEE mains 2019

> **Solution:** The speed of light in a medium is given by : $$ v= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon \mu}}$$ where $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ are the permittivity and permeability of the medium respectively.
> The relative permittivity and permeability can be written as:
> Now, since $n= \frac{c}{v}$ and $\epsilon= \epsilon_o \epsilon_r$ and $\mu_r \mu_o=\mu$, we get that
> $$ n=\sqrt{\epsilon_r \mu_r}$$
> Then the following approximation was used **$\mu_r=1$ for transparent media** which gives $n^2 = \epsilon_r$  then the intensity of light is related from the equation $I= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon E^2 \cdot v$ for both mediums, which gives:
> $$ \frac{1}{2} \epsilon E^2 \cdot \frac{c}{n}= \frac12 \epsilon_o E_o^2 \cdot c$$ which gives:
> $$ \frac{E_o}{E_m}= \sqrt{n}$$
> From this and the equation $ \frac{E}{B}=c$ on both medium, we can  derive the expression for magnetic field $\frac{B_o}{B_m} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ which is the final answer.

**The doubt I have in the above solution is I can't understand how the approximation $\mu_r=1$ was arrived at**.  I understand that the medium must be transparent because light passed through without any loss (intuitive idea) but I can't understand how that implies a condition on the magnetic permeability.

I have already tried searching a justification for the above approximation on google with no results.

Comment: Are you sure the reasoning for $\mu_r = 1$ follows from having a transparent medium ? Id rather say that for transparent media the el. susceptibility (or finally the refractive index) is not imganiary. And many of those materials also do not enhance nor decrease a magnetic field, i.e. they react to a magnetic field the same way tha vacuum does. And that gives rise to $\mu_r = 1$

Comment: "electric  susceptibility  is not imaginary" how did you conclude this? and I think you may have the answer I was looking for could you write more about the last point ? @Martin